# Error in map function "Int is not iterable"

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am getting unexpected error in map function.(Python)

Why this is giving error?

```py
x=[1,2]
print(list(map(list,x)))
```

But below code is running correctly?

```py
x=['a','b']
print(list(map(list,x)))
```

Comment: A string object is *iterable* where as an *int* object is not

Comment: You can reduce this example to `list(1)`, which yields the same error. Why would you expect this to work and what should it do?

Answer (score 1):

The `list` function requires its argument as an `iterable`. But `int` is not an iterable.

If you do:

```py
list('abcd')
```

Output:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

It is because it iterates over each element and then produces a `list`.

If you would like to create similar functionality as per for `x=['a','b']`,

```py
print(list(map(lambda y: [y], x)))
```

Output:

> [[1], [2]]

`lambda` creates an anonymous function with argument `y`, which is the current item in the list `x` and places the single element in the `list` created and NOT iterate over it.